# VAR equivalent in C# 2015

Tags: c#

I built a project in C# using VS 2017, then realized that Installshield was not available I did add the MS installer but wanted to use installshield so I fired up VS 2015 and loaded the project had 4 errors in the following code. var and video ID do not exist in the current context. CS5013 any help would be appreciated.

```
  /// <summary>
    /// If given a YouTube URL, parses video id from it.
    /// Otherwise returns the same string.
    /// </summary>
    private static string NormalizeVideoId(string input)
    {
        return YoutubeClient.TryParseVideoId(input, out var videoId)
            ? videoId
            : input;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS2015 doesn't support C# 7, and `out var videoId` is C# 7 syntax. If you are really stuck on using InstallShield rather than trying out the Microsoft installer, you could fix this line by explicitly defining the variable:

```
string videoId = string.Empty; //assuming it's a string

return YoutubeClient.TryParseVideoId(input, out videoId)
    ? videoId
    : input;
```

Of course, you may find many more issues in your code that also use newer syntax.

Comment: Here is the issue I installed the Microsoft installer it was listed once in other project types but it is not shown any more I tried to reinstall it but it says its already installed so I am really in a catch 22

Comment: That's a different question/problem though.

Comment: Isn't the initialization with `string.Empty` unnecessary?

Comment: @UweKeim True, it's just a habit of mine to explicitly initialise variables.

Comment: I'm trained by ReSharper to avoid things like this  .

Comment: A little off the original topic but I thought I would add this here for others. I found that vs 2017 has an extension for Advanced Installer installing it now and here is a tutorial for how to use https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-ai-ext-vs.html